# Does NSUserDefault take a few seconds to register the values I pass it?

Tags: iphone, object, nsuserdefaults, nsinteger

I am passing an integer value to the NSUserDefault object to store for use when my app loads up. I ***HAD*** it working perfectly until I tried to switch that integer value to a float. It caused a whole bunch of problems, so I re-adjusted my approach, and command-z'd my way back to the safety of integers...or so I thought.

It used to be that if I saved the value, I could close my simulator immediately, and the console would spit out the correctly saved number without problem. NOW, after that stupid float mess (Could I have corrupted my NSUserDefault object? That just sounds stupid...), getting the right number to display is somewhat of a gamble.

I have gone through with a bunch of NSLogs, and can confirm that the value I save when I hit save is correctly being passed to the set method in the UserDefault class. The set method gets the value correctly, and then sets it to the NSUD object like so:

```
[self setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:num] forKey:savedNum];
```

When I run the get method on that object, the console prints out the value correctly. When the app loads up, it calls the SAME get method I just tested, but it doesn't always return the right thing. Often times, it is the previous save's value that shows up.

If I hit the save button and wait 5 seconds before closing the app, it has worked correctly before, but its rare. If I wait 10 seconds, it spits out the right number.

Why would time have anything to do with this operation? I am just at a complete loss as to why this is occurring, especially because I had it working correctly just yesterday...

Any thoughts or input would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you make sure to `-synchronize` the NSUserDefaults?

Comment: I am not familiar with that, how do I synchronize?

Comment: Good call - but I think that only controls it getting written out to flash. (According to the docs) It keeps an "in-memory cache" - which should make things consistent on readback - even before it's been written out to flash.

Comment: @Jerry Do [nsudobjectnamehere synchronize].

Comment: @Brad: Not sure what you're meaning here. As far as I can tell, -synchronize should write it to disk and update the in-memory version to the on-disk. Since you're basically going to only going through the singleton userdefaults, there shouldn't be a case where, after a synchronize, there would be a place with the wrong out of date values.

Answer (score 1):

I've never noticed that behavior - and I don't think it is the case that there is a delay involved.

So the most obvious question is:

If you do a:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:value ForKey:@"myInteger"];
NSLog(@"It is %d",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"myInteger"]);
```

Do you get the correct value?

Comment: Yes, throwing the above NSLog in with some of my others produced the same value. If it is before I shut the app down, it is correct, if it is while its loading it up, it produces the wrong number...so weird!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a simulator bug. With your application on the simulated device, open up Settings.app. Now exit Settings.app. Your defaults settings will suddenly begin working.

See also this thread on the Apple discussion forums about the [non-sticky `NSUserDefaults` issue](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=6996592).

Comment: So just in the simulator, go into the Settings app, like the one with the gears? Open then close? I tried that and it didn't help...I am going to throw it onto my device when I get home and see if that helps. I HOPE this is just a simulator bug...thanks

Comment: I know I ran into this same simulator problem and that dance seemed to fix it for me. :\ Sorry!